# Encriptar/Desencriptar parámetro GET por URL con PHP

Tags: php, encriptación, get

Quiero pasar un ID por la URL y que esté dato quede encriptado al usuario.

Hasta ahora he usado `base64_encode`, pero me han recomendado que use otros métodos.

Envío los datos de esta forma:

```
<a href="paginanueva?id='. base64_encode($id) .'" >Ir a form</a>;
```

Y los recojo así:

```
$idrecogido = base64_decode($_GET['id']);
```

Como veis es algo muy básico, pero desconozco totalmente este tema... Qué otra solución segura me dais?? alguna solución funcional para encriptar/desencriptar que sea "sencillo" pero a la vez seguro?

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que quieres conseguir con eso? Es decir, se me hace raro que el cliente tenga que pasarte información que él mismo desconoce. Es posible que más que cifrar la información, deberías no ponerla a la vista en el HTML

Comment: Es que esto que usas, con el debido respeto, no es encriptación. con un poco de paciencia, se puede poner en claro lo que se está pasando. Es mejor lo que te propone @aruetre. Yo añadiría que la clave esté en un fichero de configuración.

Answer (score 3):

En un principio te recomiendo que uses un sistema de cifrado mediante clave generada mediante una cadena larga.

```
class Enigma {

  private static $Key = "CLAVESUPERSECRETA";

  public static function encrypt ($string) {
     return base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5(Enigma::$Key),
     $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5(Enigma::$Key))));
  }

  public static function decrypt ($string) {
     return rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5(Enigma::$Key), 
     base64_decode($string), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5(Enigma::$Key))), "\0");
  }

}
```

Comment: Funciona perfectamente, el único problema que veo, es que depende de la $key, a veces genera una cadena que incluye símbolos como "+" y no funciona correctamente al hacer el decrypted. Alguna solución??

Comment: Usa solo caracteres alfanumericos sin acentuar de la a-z A-Z 0 1234567890, nada de acentos ni ñ, y en caso que siga saliendo + retiralos con replace. me refiero $key

Comment: Disculpa supongo que te falla al decodificar al venir por la url no? seguramente es porque el + es un caracter reservado de http para concatenar variables pasadas por url

Comment: Si eso es, me falla al decodificar lo que viene por la url, solo en algunos casos en los que aparece el caracter +. Gracias por la información y por toda tu ayuda!

Comment: Estas empleando urlencode y url decode http://php.net/manual/es/function.urlencode.php